# Why there is no Market Place for windows?

Tags: windows, windows-store

I know

I know

I know

There is [Window Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps-and-games) for windows 8, 8.1, and 10(*powered by Microsoft*). But why there is no third party app store to share `*.exe` mini application? (like some applications for converting the units or something)

there is a lot of store that share `*.apk` in android (good or bad) but why there is not in Windows 7, 8, 8.1 and 10?

**possible answer:** Because there is no executable file in Window Store application,,, But I don't mean the Window Store Application, I mean the normal desktop application like some `C# winform apps`.

I follow the critical problem of it, because this is obviously a necessary program for every one...

Comment: @downvoter, explain me why

Comment: Maybe, ideally there *should* be, at least someplace where you can get programs that have been checked & verified to be clean. Like chocolatey, which looks to be modeled after linux-style repositories. Just look into Linux ;-)

Comment: @MehdiKhademloo - The reason there isn't a third-party Universal Windows Application Store is simple, Windows 8 and above, wouldn't run any Windows Store not signed by Microsoft.  There are ways to run your own unreleased application, that but that requires specific knowledge on how to do it, is not trivial, and requires certain requirements to be fulfilled for it to be possible.  *There certainly is a executable file for the Windows Store application.*

Comment: @Ramhound What do you mean? I generally talking about sharing `.exe` files. If there is no Microsoft permission, how can Microsoft ban my application? I simply run it like any other window desktop program

Answer (score 1):

There are some other tools like https://chocolatey.org/ which provide a way to install normal desktop tools in a NuGet style. Take a look at it.